# Java "Supported Versions Affected" column in Critical Patch Update Advisory

Tags: java, security, patch

Oracle releases quarterly **Critical Patch Update Advisory** which has the "Oracle Java SE Risk Matrix". In this matrix I see all the new findings and details with **Supported Versions Affected** info. My concern is in this column only **one** minor version listed for most of the major versions, like CVE-2018-2938 has only listed  **6**u191, **7**u181, **8**u172. I haven't find any comment if this means only the listed **exact** versions are affected (and nothing before, what would be surprising) **or all prior** versions are affected.

Checking other tables in this report like "Oracle MySQL Risk Matrix" or "Oracle Retail Applications Risk Matrix" I can see versions listed in the same column and commented like "and prior" or marked like 1.x which includes all prior versions as well.

Is there any **official** statement, how should we interpret the "Supported Versions Affected" column in the "Oracle Java SE Risk Matrix"? Is it only the listed version or all prior? If all prior are affected why don't they mention or mark on the same way as they do in other tables?

I would prefer some official statement or URL as this is really confusing and as a security question we should not guess.

Thank you,

Zsolt

Comment: Previous minor versions aren't **supported**, so that's why they're not included.

Comment: Does this mean when 8u172 has been released the 8u171 is out of support?

Comment: `172` is made to fix things in `171` (and before), so it's actually the supported version of Java 8. How would you continue to support a previous minor version? You could use Micro versions, but Java doesn't have them and it would be useless.

Comment: If this is the case and by default the new minor version replaces the current supported version why do they mark other products with "and prior" and 1.x? It is so confusing.

Comment: I can't really answer that, but I suppose if a company is security aware, they wouldn't be running any older versions than the most recent one.

Comment: Agree with you but a thing like security and sec notifications like these which effects zillion of devices should be clear and this is really strange for me no one has a strict understanding and there is not description which helps understand the table and everyone guessing..